# How can I use a printer font (non-TrueType) in OpenOffice.org Writer?

Tags: printer, fonts, openoffice

A printer driver with a special font is installed on my system which can only be used if I set the printer to this driver in text editors like Wordpad or Word.

In OpenOffice.org Writer, I can choose the printer driver but the font list does not contain this font.

How can I add this font so that it ca nbe used in the document?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the font folder that was included in the driver to the Windows Font folder and see if it makes a difference. OpenOffice is supposed to be able to automatically detect fonts the same exact way Microsoft Word does.